# Regex Replace [ with -> depending on a condition

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex that could replace all "[" with an "->" but only when it's not followed by "]".

And replace at the same time all of the "]" with nothing, but only when they are not next to an "["

So in other word "test[hi][]" will be become "test->hi[]"

Thank you ;)

I really have no clue how to do that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made the assumptions that what exist between the brackets follows [PHP variable naming conventions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) (i.e. letters, digits, underscores) and your code is valid (e.g. no `$test['five]`).

```
echo preg_replace('/\[[\'"]?(\w+)[\'"]?\]/', '->\1', $input);
```

This should handle:

```
test[one]
test['two']
test["three"]
```

But not:

```
test[$four]
```

Comment: I don't think he needs to match quotes.

Answer (score 4):

No regexp needed!

```
strtr($str, array('[]'=>'[]','['=>'->',']'=>''))




$ cat 1.php
<?php
echo strtr('[hi][]', array('[]'=>'[]','['=>'->',']'=>''));
$ php 1.php
->hi[]
```

Comment: +1 for not using a regex. But it should be noted that this only works for this specific format (i.e. `arr[key]`). You'll likely need to embrace regexes if you have different *keys*.

Comment: DON'T use regular expressions, if you can solve task without it. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

This should do. It uses

```
\[     # match a [
(      # match group
[^\]]+ # match everything but a ] one or more times
)      # close match group 
\]     # match ]
```

to match anything between brackets

```
$replaced = preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", "->$1", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this regex `\[(\w+)\]` with `->` + match group 1